# Omitted Variable Bias and Causal Relationships between Independent Variables

Tags: regression, inference, causality

I am working on a linear modeling task and I'm trying to find the right variables to include in the model. I need to estimate whether the causal effect of *one* independent variable on the percentage change of the dependent variable over a time period of 5 years (1951-1956) is significant.

The variable I need to isolate the causal effect from is the dummy variable "household bought one or more cars between 1951-1956". I.e. "1", if the household did buy a car in that period, and "0" if the household did not.

The issue I encountered is that one covariate I have available to include in the model is the following:

"share of households that using the car as their main mode of transportation, ***as of 1956*** ", so it only refers to the end of the period.

The problem I encountered is that this variable is correlated with both the dependent variable I want to estimate the causal effect of ($cor \approx 0.22$, significant), but also the independent variable ($cor \approx 0.08$, significant). Hence, this would normally be a case of an omitted variable bias if I were not include it in the model.

However, of course it is extremely intuitive to think that if a household buys a car, it is highly more likely that it might become their main mode of transportation. Or what might even be a larger problem is that the car *can only become* the main mode of transportation *if* the household buys a car in the first place. Lastly, the variable is taken at the end of the period, in ***1956***, while all the other covariates refer to the entire period.

And yet I heard that it is still better to include variables that may cause an omitted variable bias at the potential cost of multicollinearity, since we might get a higher variance, but at least the estimator is unbiased.

Should I include the variable in the model?

Comment: I think another issue to think about is getting your causality backwards. E.g. if your dependant variable is getting a high paying job (with the idea that with a car you can travel further and get a better job), but if you don't have the temporal ordering right (i.e. you don't know whether someone had a car before they applied for the job), you might see a relationship just because someone with a high paying job is more likely to buy a car due to now having enough money. If you cannot establish the temporal order of things you may have a really hard time establishing any credible causality.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah that's the thing – I don't know if the household actually already had a car before the period began. Would that be a reason to rather not include that variable?

Comment: That would be a reason to doubt that you can get something casual established. Amongst two options that are provably wrong, it can be hard to know which one will be less bad and exactly how bad it is.